# Can I audit with the audit gem and not store the changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have started using the audited gem in a Rails 3 application.

It works fine but I have a problem that I have a table with a large text column.
I **dont** want to save the data from this column in the 'audited_changes' of the audits table as the table would blow out in size.

I know I can suppress auditing on that column with something like :except=>:my_big_text_column

So in summary I **do** want to know that the user has edited the text but I **dont** want to save a copy of that text every time. If I suppress audits on that column I get no audit rec at all if they edit the column.

Comment: Have you tried to disable auditing for that column like here https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited#disabling-auditing ?

Comment: yes I have but then there is no record of the column changing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out an answer that works for how I want to audit.
I just created my own version of Audited::Adapters::ActiveRecord::Audit and put it in initializers.

I added a before_save method to manipulate the audited_changes hash.
I just changed the hash to just say "changed" for the specified big text column.
Seems to do what I need.

```
 module Audited
  module Adapters
    module ActiveRecord
      class Audit < ::ActiveRecord::Base
        before_save :remove_text_fields

        def remove_text_fields
          if self.audited_changes.include?("case_notes")
            self.audited_changes["case_notes"]="changed"
          end
        end

      end
    end
  end
end
```